# Python 3: print('...'), do stuff, print('done') on the same line

Tags: python-3.x, printing

I'd like to print an update on what's processing, then process it, then print a 'done' statement. The code below prints "waiting ... done" after the 2 second sleep finishes. How can I get the first print statement to execute before the code between the print statements executes?

```
import time
print("waiting ...", end=" ")
time.sleep(2)
print("done")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's buffered. You need to flush the buffer:

```
print("waiting ...", end=" ", flush=True)
```

Comment: Easy enough, thank you!